# Regarding the vernal equinox and calculate a TLE code

Tags: coordinates, two-line-elements

I am utterly confused as to how the ecliptic co ordinate system works.
My understanding is that the vernal equinox is comparable to greenwich for longitude here on earth. But how do we know where the vernal equinox is normal to on earth?

For example, if I launch a hypothetical satellite into polar orbit, how do I find the right ascension of the ascending node? Presumably it depends on the time it goes through the ascending node?

Complete beginner here utterly lost.